# Attachment editor esri duplicate files

Tags: javascript, events, attachments, arcgis-api-wpf

I am using arcgis API's attachment editor 
      var attachmentEditor = new AttachmentEditor({}, dom.byId("content"));
          attachmentEditor.startup();

```
 featureLayer.on("click", function(evt) {
        var objectId = evt.graphic.attributes[featureLayer.objectIdField];
        map.infoWindow.setTitle(objectId);
        attachmentEditor.showAttachments(evt.graphic,featureLayer);
        map.infoWindow.show(evt.screenPoint,map.getInfoWindowAnchor(evt.screenPoint));
      });
      map.addLayer(featureLayer);
```

i have written a code on file change button to check for duplicates files

```
$("input[type='file'][name='attachment']").change(function(e){ 

                     var file=e.target.files[0];
                            for (var a in attachments){
                                    if (attachments[a].contentType === file.type &&  attachments[a].name === file.name && attachments[a].size === file.size)
                                    {
                                        console.log("duplicate");
                                        e.stopPropagation();
                                        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                } 



                });
```

now i want to stop event propagation to stop so that files doesnt get attached! but the esri onchange event also triggers and the file gets attached. how to stop propogation? so that only my onchange event gets called.